# How do I add a "focus lost" event listener to ZK elements?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, zk

I have a Bandbox element which needs an event listener for losing focus/clicking outside.
There's a '[focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event)' event in JavaScript but since it's not defined in the ZK 'Events' class I cannot use it as an argument.

Or is there a way to bypass the validation in the 'Events' class so I can use:

```
myBandbox.addEventListener("focusout", (event) -> {
                // do something
            });
```

If not is there an alternative to adding a click listener for the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that the `ON_BLUR`-Event does the job:

```
myBandbox.addEventListener(Events.ON_BLUR, (event) -> {
            // do something
        });
```